# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /getThing from myapp.herokuapp.com to http://localhost:3001

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I have a MERN stack app built using Facebook's [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) template and Nodejs/Express. I am using [Heroku's Nodejs Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs). I was able to deploy my app to Heroku after ["Dangerously Disabling Host Check"](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy).

[**Reproducible Demo**](https://github.com/abagh0703/cra-proxy-error) (instructions in readme)

My site displays information, but requests to my back-end don't work (both the server and React run on the same Heroku app). When my site tries to make a request to an endpoint such as /getThing, the browser console displays this:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/getThing
Line Number 1, Column 1:
getThing:1:1
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

My `Heroku logs` gives me this (only relevant portion included):

```
2018-03-11T04:27:01.058036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/getThing" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=e587a6ee-1dbf-4a2d-9caf-07d9478b5a39 fwd="128.84.126.1
26" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=297 protocol=https
2018-03-11T04:27:01.032269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bundle.js.map" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a4fd078d-07f1-4796-b0fe-555f8f389920 fwd="128.84.126.126"
 dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=176 protocol=https
2018-03-11T04:27:01.055673+00:00 app[web.1]: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /getThing from myapp.herokuapp.com to http://localhost:3001/.
2018-03-11T04:27:01.055735+00:00 app[web.1]: See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
2018-03-11T04:27:01.055787+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-03-11T04:27:02.212247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs-node/info?t=1520742420523" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=91c5363e-dbf3-4d15-9482-b44bc1dc3205 fwd="128.84
.126.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=363 protocol=https
```

The 4th line is where the error is. I've been [using a proxy](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) in my package.json, but I've read Heroku ignores that so it shouldn't be a problem. My package.json is included below.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.2.1",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.205.0",
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.4.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "foreman": "^2.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "marked": "^0.3.17",
    "milligram": "^1.3.0",
    "milligram-react": "0.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.35",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.11",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.7.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-table": "^6.8.0",
    "sendgrid-web": "0.0.5",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "supports-color": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "engines": { "node": "6.11.3", "npm": "5.7.1"},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start | node server.js",
    "start-dev": "set DEBUG=* & nodemon server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

And here's the server code to start the server:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, function () {
    debug(`api running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I'm even allowing [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) everywhere:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

File structure:

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: I deployed your app and reproduced the issue. So you have multiple issues here. The proxy is actually used to send the request to `3001` but in your `server.js`, you use `const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;` which means you don't use `3001`. You use the random port that heroku provides. Also you should not be using `Procfile`, that will launch two dynos. You can launch them both in same. This article explains how it should be done https://originmaster.com/running-create-react-app-and-express-crae-on-heroku-c39a39fe7851. Will post a detailed answer tomorrow, this will help you fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have few issues here.

> Heroku runs one web dyno for you automatically, but other process types don’t start by default. To launch a worker, you need to scale it up to one dyno:

Which means by default your API dyno is not even up. You need to execute below command to get it up

```
heroku ps:scale api=1
```

But then also it won't help because, your API is not `http` reachable and has `web` dyno has no way of known where the `api` is. There is possibility to do that, but I won't go into that solution for this answer

You can find more details on below

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-dns-service-discovery

You might need to change your `server.js` like below

```
const host = process.env.HEROKU_PRIVATE_IP || '0.0.0.0';
//starts the server and listens for requests
app.listen(port, host, function () {
    debug(`api running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and also update `package.json` to

```
"proxy": "http://<apidnsname>:3001"
```

But as I said I would not prefer that solution as it needs to hardcode the `dnsname` in the `package.json`.

**Actual Fix**

- Delete the Procfile (heroku will automatically run `npm start`)
- Add the concurrently package `npm add concurrently`
- Change the `start` script to `"start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"PORT=3001 node server.js\""`. This does two things. Fixes the PORT for your api server process. And also starts the server in the same dyno, so it can be reached over the same `localhost` network

Deploy the app and now it works

[image: Deployed heroku app]

Below is a sample working app for you to check, which will be live for sometime and then I will remove it

https://soproxyapp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This works perfectly on heroku! While not an issue for me, with this method I receive the same error when running locally on localhost. Out of curiosity, do you know why that is?

Comment: I tested and works in local also. You should use `npm start`

Comment: Is there a reason that such a simple app takes so long to load? I don't think it's a problem with the Heroku free plan because not all Heroku free sites are this slow. Doing those online speed tests gives you a low number but actually trying to load the site is very slow on the first load or two. Any ideas as to how this can be changed?

Comment: Seems like the websocket handshake takes a decent amount of time. On mine it took nearly `1.6min`

Comment: Interesting... Do you know of any solution to this? If not I can make another question.

Comment: No idea. Better open a new question. And can you accept this one?